# Catching java exceptions FileNotFound and IOException at the same time

Tags: java, ioexception, filenotfoundexception

Is the FileNotFoundException somehow a "sub-exception" of the IOException?

This is my code opening an input stream to a file at the given path:

```
   method(){
        FileInputStream fs;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(path);
            //
            fs.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How come I can neglect the FileNotFound and just catch the IOException instead? 
Is the FNFException a part of the IOException?

Instead of catching the exceptions, what if I throw an IOException in my method?

```
    method() throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fs;
        fs = new FileInputStream(path);
        //
        fs.close();

    }
```

Can I proceed to catch a FileNotFoundException at the invoking method like this?

```
    try {

         method();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {}
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is the FileNotFoundException somehow a "sub-exception" of the IOException?

Yes, [`FileNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) *extends* `IOException`:

> ```
> java.lang.Object
>     java.lang.Throwable
>         java.lang.Exception
>             java.io.IOException
>                 java.io.FileNotFoundException
> ```
>
> How come I can neglect the FileNotFound and just catch the IOException instead?

Catching a base class of the exception being thrown will catch the exception, unless there is a more specific `catch` clause available.

> Can I proceed to catch a FileNotFoundException at the invoking method like this?

Absolutely! In fact, this is a good thing to do: your code should handle only the exceptions with which it knows how to deal, and let all other exceptions propagate to a place where it could be dealt with in a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.

If you look at inheritance `FileNotFoundException` is a sub-class of `IOException`. By catching the super class you also catch anything that extends it.

You can catch the more specific one first as in your first example if you need to handle it differently.

Answer (score 3):

From Java 7 onwards you can do:

`catch(ExceptionType1 | ExceptionType2 e)` to do multiple-exception catches. However, in your case, you can just catch the IOException, as you suggest.

Comment: This is true, but a red herring in this case. You don't need to catch disparate exception types when one extends the other.

Comment: Answer modified after my comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Is the FileNotFoundException somehow a "sub-exception" of the IOException?

[Yes it is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html).

> Instead of catching the exceptions, what if I throw an IOException in my method?

You can do so. When a method throws an excpetion, it can throw this exception in particular or any exception inheriting it.

> Can I proceed to catch a FileNotFoundException at the invoking method like this?

Yes. If a method declares to throw `A`, you can catch `B` if `B` inherits `A` (even if `B` isn't thrown by `A` explicitly).

Side note:

- you don't close your resources correctly;
- if you use Java 7, use the new Files API instead.

The first point is very important. You `.close()` in your `try` block; if you can successfully open the file but fail to read from it or whatever, `.close()` will *not* be called. You should do:

```
FileInputStream in = ...;
try {
    // operate on "in"
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

For Java 7:

```
try (
    FileInputStream in = ...;
) {
    // operate on "in"
}
// "in" is closed for you here
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) shows it, `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`.

If you really want`FileNotFoundException`, you must catch only this execption, otherwise catching `IOException` will also catch any exception subclassing it, like `FileNotFoundException` any many others.